# Solve $2\cos x-2=\sin^2x$.

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve $2\cos x - 2 = \sin^2x$ for the interval $0\leq x\leq 2\pi$. Determine the value of the variable in radians.

[Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw1Xi.png)

It would be greatly appreciated if you can point me in the right direction!

Comment: **Hint**: $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: That tip seems to come in handy fairly often. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$2\cos x-2=1-\cos^2x\implies\cos^2x+2\cos x-3=0$$

Put $\;t=\cos x\;$ and solve the easy quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

> $$2\cos x-2=\sin^2x$$

$\sin^2x=1-\cos^2 x$ so

$$2\cos x-2=1-\cos^2 x$$

Set $t:=\cos x$

$$2\cdot t -2=1-t^2$$

$$t_1=-3,\quad t_2=1$$

$\cos x=-3$ there is no solution because $-1\leq \cos x \leq 1$

$\cos x=1$ when $\boxed{x=0,x=2\pi}$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $\cos{x}-1=1/2(\sin^2x)\geq{0}$ which means that $\cos{x}\geq1$ i.e. $\cos{x}=1$ . Then, the only possible value of $x$ which might be a solution is $0$ or $2\pi$. One readily checks that these are in fact (the) solutions.